# send graph for specific period of time from aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, datadog

Is there any way to send matrics graph over email for a specific period of time from AWS Cloudwatch or by using datadog.

I want to send ec2 system check matrics for a specific time period.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is a matrix graph? Which dimensions do you want to have in?

Comment: @hansaplast i want to see the graph for system check for a ec2 instance for only specific period of time (production hours)

Comment: so you want `StatusCheckFailed_System`?

Comment: @hansaplast . yes

Comment: this check only fails when there's a hardware failure of an aws host. This will happen very rarely (e.g. 1-2 times per year). Why would you want a graph of that? Don't you want alarms when the system is down and then get the graph manually?

Comment: @hansaplast actually there are multiple instances and i need report daily. I think i have to do something with Api.